# Removing compilation metadata from Python

Tags: python, makefile, configure

I use Python in one of my products.

I compiled the source code using:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/myname/python_install
make
make install.
```

I looked inside python_install directory and noticed that many files (config, pyc, pyo), disclose information about my environment (i.e. strings with where i compiled it, directory, date, name, etc..)

I used '`grep -i -r "myname"' *`

How do I remove this metadata from all those files? I do not want to ship my product with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not something you have to worry about.  Is it a secret where you stored your files?  If so, choose a different directory name to begin with.  Otherwise, I doubt you're going to be able to remove all trace of its location.

BTW, shipping a Python project means an interested party could basically read your Python source, so why worry about the locations of the files?

Comment: I wasn't talking about the Python source, i was talking about information about my environment (compilation directory for example that includes my username).

Comment: Yes, I understand.  I think it might be difficult to expunge all of that information everywhere.  Are you sure you need to?  Can you create your project in a different location to begin with?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do now.